# Hiding the Navigation Bar Created Without any NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am going crazy over this! I need to hide the navigation bar which was created without a `navigation controller` (I dont know how and why you can do that).
[image]

I have tried creating an outlet to the uinavigationbar and then hiding that but everytime I do that the uinavigationbar outlet is `null`.

**RESOLVED**:

```
 controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TermsStoryboard"];


            for(UIView *subView in controller.view.subviews)
            {
                if([subView isKindOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]])
                {
                    [subView setHidden:YES];

                    NSLog(@"Navigation Bar Found!");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why not remove it from the view? I am confused as to what you are ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you sure that the IBOutlet is wired correctly?

Comment: I agree! The above code makes no sense at all

Comment: Have you created outlets to anything else before? Creating one for the navigation bar is no different than making one to any other UI element.